# EMGUCV TriangulatePoint result dimension

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using TriangulatePoints from EmguCV to get 3D point coordinates from two 2D points. What is dimension of the result from TriangulatePoints - meters, santimeters? I've got result which is meaningful if count it as in kilometers!

The programm is:

```
Mat pnts3D = new Mat(4, 1, DepthType.Cv32F, 1);
var distortedvector1 = new VectorOfPointF(new System.Drawing.PointF[] { new System.Drawing.PointF(pixel1.X, pixel1.Y) });
var undistortedvector1 = new VectorOfPointF(1);
var distortedvector2 = new VectorOfPointF(new System.Drawing.PointF[] { new System.Drawing.PointF(pixel2.X, pixel2.Y) });
var undistortedvector2 = new VectorOfPointF(1);

CvInvoke.UndistortPoints(distortedvector1, undistortedvector1, Cam1.Intrinsic, Cam1.Distortion);
CvInvoke.UndistortPoints(distortedvector2, undistortedvector2, Cam2.Intrinsic, Cam2.Distortion);

try
{
    CvInvoke.TriangulatePoints(Cam1.Projection, Cam2.Projection, undistortedvector1, undistortedvector2, pnts3D);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}

var result = MatBytesToFloatArray(pnts3D);
var w = result[3];
var retvector3 = new Vector3((float)(result[0] / w), (float)(result[1] / w), (float)(result[2] / w));
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Cam1.Distortion (14):[481,502689627429, -841,648758481293, 0,0257660673736087, -0,00664883109048042, 1241,13243728613, 485,26933532528, -623,788622974316, -1219,25905617368, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Cam2.Distortion (14):[20,1044879177662, -1190,59956948171, 0,0274736201501511, -0,00848979945593021, 354,932615682399, 18,1047848497052, -1111,48717514417, -367,284797989649, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Cam1.Intrinsic:rows=3, cols=3
[1421,6232200842,   0,  320,23862758755,    ]
[0, 1428,98745892452,   199,944687601858,   ]
[0, 0,  1,  ]
 
Cam2.Intrinsic:rows=3, cols=3
[2076,57647581115,  0,  394,114254194307,   ]
[0, 2094,42536111494,   377,096640881492,   ]
[0, 0,  1,  ]
 
Cam1.Extrinsic:rows=3, cols=4
[1, 0,  0,  0,  ]
[0, 1,  0,  0,  ]
[0, 0,  1,  0,  ]
 
Cam2.Extrinsic:rows=3, cols=4
[-0,93268516519841, -0,155279935103946, 0,325555716234456,  -1,00600758006487,  ]
[0,170173917551302, -0,985256953588763, 0,0175946921039373, -0,264143769854773, ]
[0,318023930552495, 0,0718113999244134, 0,945359139394568,  0,868628255927857,  ]
 
Cam1.Projection:rows=3, cols=4
[1421,6232200842,   0,  320,23862758755,    0,  ]
[0, 1428,98745892452,   199,944687601858,   0,  ]
[0, 0,  1,  0,  ]
 
Cam2.Projection:rows=3, cols=4
[-1811,45430918341, -294,148764078476,  1048,62085406658,   -1746,7128979933,   ]
[476,342324651005,  -2036,46731312266,  393,342525255805,   -225,672613079203,  ]
[0,318023930552495, 0,0718113999244134, 0,945359139394568,  0,868628255927857,  ]
 
-------------------------------------------------
distortedvector1 (1):[{X=320,501, Y=133,508}]
distortedvector2 (1):[{X=368,494, Y=57,5099}]
undistortedvector1 (1):[{X=0,000200561, Y=-0,04687342}]
undistortedvector2 (1):[{X=-0,01204917, Y=-0,1520803}]

TriangulatePoints result (4): [ -0,2025533, -0,02141375,    0,7237045,  0,6593674]

retvector3 (Vector length (meters):1,140215): [ -0,3071934, -0,0324762, 1,097574]

------------------------------------------------
distortedvector1 (1):[{X=341,518, Y=137,487}]
distortedvector2 (1):[{X=398,501, Y=55,5}]
undistortedvector1 (1):[{X=0,0150876, Y=-0,04406969}]
undistortedvector2 (1):[{X=0,002294832, Y=-0,1530818}]

TriangulatePoints result (4): [ -0,2025492, -0,02141088,    0,7237136,  0,6593587]

retvector3 (Vector length (meters):1,140242): [ -0,3071912, -0,03247228,    1,097602]
```

Some changes in the result occurs only 4 or 5 digits after decimal point, and if count result numbers as kilometers - everything is OK! Is this correct, or I've made something wrong?